# How do I uninstall a Windows service if the files do not exist anymore?

Tags: windows, windows-services, installation

How do I uninstall a .NET Windows Service if the service files do not exist anymore?

I installed a .NET Windows Service using InstallUtil. I have since deleted the files but forgot to run

```
 InstallUtil /u
```

first, so the service is still listed in the Services MMC.

Do I have to go into the registry? Or is there a better way?

Comment: [Delserv](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229)

Comment: Did you also stop the service first? (--> net stop yourservice)

Comment: A very closely related thread [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76074/465053).

Comment: this site help me and I hope will help you in this problem https://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/how-to-delete-a-windows-service-in-vista-or-xp/

Comment: You can use [NSSM](https://nssm.cc). Just type 'remove <service name>'

Answer (score 1218, accepted):

You have at least three options. I have presented them in order of usage preference.

**Method 1** -  You can use the [SC tool](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/251192) (Sc.exe) included in the Resource Kit. 
(included with Windows 7/8)

Open a Command Prompt and enter

```
sc delete <service-name>
```

Tool help snippet follows:

```
DESCRIPTION:
        SC is a command line program used for communicating with the
        NT Service Controller and services.

delete----------Deletes a service (from the registry).
```

**Method 2** - use delserv

[Download](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927229) and use delserv command line utility. This is a legacy tool developed for Windows 2000. In current Window XP boxes this was superseded by sc described in method 1.

**Method 3** - manually delete registry entries **(Note that this backfires in Windows 7/8)**

Windows services are registered under the following registry key.

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
```

Search for the sub-key with the service name under referred key and delete it. (and you might need to restart to remove completely the service from the Services list)

Comment: Method 3 seems to back-fire on Windows 7.

Comment: At method 1, you may experience "The specified service does not exist as an installed service" error, although you see the service at the MMC!!! This is because the name you see is the DisplayName. You may lookup the actual service name at HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services tree and pass *that* as service-name.

Comment: Method 3 backfired for me too on Windows 7. Service is there now with Description `<Failed to Read Description. Error Code: 2>`

Comment: note be careful if you are using powershell with sc - it overrides the application with it's set-content cmdlet and if you run sc delete blah it silently fails

Comment: @Zugwalt try signing out and signing back in again - this solved the "Read Description" error for me, the service was now gone from the service manager window

Comment: Remember if you are using Method 1 and your service name has spaces in its name, surround the service name in double quotes. Your windows needs a restart to eliminate the service name from the MMC list.

Comment: @smink How do you do this programmatically? I mean how can I put it in my installer code so that prior to the installation, if any previous instance prevails on that machine, it will be deleted.

Comment: After using Method 1, I had to restart Windows 7 for the service to be deleted.

Comment: Method 1 seems to work for me on Win 7 and if you refresh the Services Control Panel the removed service disappears without a reboot.

Comment: Related to "Method 1", an easier way of finding the Service Name than looking in the registry is by displaying the property sheet for the service in the Services application.  (Right-click on the service and select "Properties")  The Service Name is the first item displayed on the General tab.

Comment: Method 3 seems to back-fire on Windows 8 as well.

Comment: NOTE: You have to restart your computer after doing Method 3! Then look at list of Services; it's probably gone now. If it's still in the list, then just do Method 1 to remove it from that list.

Comment: Just a note for whoever trying to execute command in Method 1 in PowerShell:
sc is not for communicating with service control manager. It is Set-Content command. Use sc.exe instead.

Comment: @smink, How does it "backfire" in Windows 8? And does it backfire in Windows 8.1?

Comment: Take an hours of trying "sc delete"
It not working in powershell (without warning or error !, it just run and keep silent !). 
Then I switch to cmd , It works perfectly !

Comment: @hungdoan this is because SC in powershell is Set-Content.

You have to use 'CMD SC' in powershell and it will also work.

Comment: At method 1, you may experience "The specified service does not exist as an installed service" error, if there is space in service name. Surround it in double quotes to resolve the issue.

Comment: Used method 1 on windows 8.1, putting quotes around the display name didn't work for me, instead I just pulled up the services window by searching for 'Services' and then I right clicked on the service I wanted to remove. In the pop up you'll see 'Service name: wookieeService' and (sometimes) 'Display name: Wookie Rendering Service'. Then typing 'sc delete wookieeService' removed it for me, I had to close and re-open the services window for it to be removed from the list.

Comment: Protip for PowerShell users: to invoke a native Windows executable/batch file/whatever instead of a PS command or alias with the same name, simply specifiy the filename **including the extension**. Thus, running `sc` in PowerShell will invoke the `Set-Content` cmdlet, while running `sc.exe` will invoke Windows' Service Control executable.

Comment: If you happen to know only the friendly (display) name of the service, this PowerShell oneliner will nuke it for you: `Get-WmiObject Win32_service -filter "displayname = '<service friendly name>'" |select -expandproperty name |foreach { sc.exe delete "$_" }`

Comment: You can also find the proper name for method 1 by going to the Services tab in Task Manager

Answer (score 189):

From the command prompt running in Administrator mode, use the Windows "sc.exe" utility.  You will run something like this:

```
sc delete <service-name>
```

If the service name has one or more spaces, surround the name in double quotes (h/t @geoffc):

```
sc delete "<service-name>"
```

Comment: If there is a space in the service name, surround it in double quotes.

Comment: Why am I getting [SC] OpenService Failed 5: Access is Denied.

Comment: @AdrianEnriquez, running cmd.exe as admin fixed this for me.

Comment: In windows 8 after using the command, the service appears with disabled status in MMC list. A restart will eliminate the service from the list.

Comment: Is there a way to elevate the privileges for this? I still get "Access is denied" after typing the above command

Comment: You might need to replace `sc` by `%Systemroot%\System32\sc.exe`

Comment: How is this knowledge aquired?

Answer (score 28):

Notes on using "sc delete" in Windows 8:

1) Open a CMD window with elevated privileges.  [Windows Key-X to bring up a menu with the option; select "Command Prompt (Admin)".]
2) Use the parenthetical name from the list in Services [for example, I used "sc delete gupdate" when, in Services, it read "Google Update (gupdate)"]

Answer (score 25):

Some people mentioning `sc delete` as an answer. This is how I did it, but it took me a while to find the `<service-name>` parameter.

The command `sc query type= service` (note, it's very particular with formatting, the space before "service" is necessary) will output a list of Windows services installed, complete with their qualified name to be used with `sc delete <service-name>` command.

The list is quite long so you may consider piping the output to a text file (i.e. `>> C:\test.txt`) and then searching through that.

The `SERVICE_NAME` is the one to use with `sc delete <service-name>` command.

Comment: See my comment on the accepted answer.  The service name can be determined quickly by looking at the Properties sheet for the service in the Services panel.

Comment: That was totally unnecessary: if they show up in the services list, you can just open the properties of the services you want to remove from the services list, *in* the services list, and it will show you the service name. The "service name" listed in the properties there is the same service name, too. :)

Comment: Yeah I know you can get to the name by other means. I added this because I had trouble figuring out which of the names to use in the command. I had seen the name listed in the service properties, but I didn't know at the time that was the name to use in the command. Using the command line was a good way for me to dump out all the installed services, including the <service_name> to use to remove. I had a couple of services that needed this so it was easier for me to dump the whole list out to file so I could get to them without having to look it up in the services snap-in.

Comment: You can just run `sc query` as it defaults to `type= service`.

Answer (score 13):

**Remove Windows Service via Registry**

Its very easy to remove a service from registry if you know the right path. Here is how I did that:

1. Run **Regedit** or **Regedt32**
2. Go to the registry entry "HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE/SYSTEM/CurrentControlSet/Services"
3. Look for the service that you want delete and delete it. You can look at the keys to know what files the service was using and delete them as well (if necessary).

**Delete Windows Service via Command Window**

Alternatively, you can also use command prompt and delete a service using following command:

**sc delete**

You can also create service by using following command

sc create "MorganTechService" binpath= "C:\Program Files\MorganTechSPace\myservice.exe"

Note: You may have to reboot the system to get the list updated in service manager.

Answer (score 12):

If you wish to use a tool for it you could use [Process Hacker](http://processhacker.sourceforge.net/)

Form to create the service:

[image: Process Hacker Create Service]

Context menu on a service to delete it:

[image: Process Hacker Delete Service]

I find Process Hacker a more convient tool to manage Windows processes and services than Windows's own Taskmgr.exe. Especially on Windows XP, where you can't access services at all from task manager.

Comment: It gives: the specified service is marked for deletion.

Answer (score 7):

I needed to reinstall my tomcat service, which meant first removing it.  This worked for me:

```
Start a command prompt window using run as administrator

sc query type= service >t.txt
```

(edit the file t.txt, search through the list and find the tomcat service.  It's called Tomcat7)

```
sc delete Tomcat7
```

HOWEVER, the query command did not work the first time, because the tomcat service was not running.  It seems to only list services that are running.  I had to start the service and run the query command again.

Comment: If you want to see stopped services, use the `state` parameter.

Comment: To see all services:

sc query type= service state= all

Answer (score 4):

If the original Service .InstallLog and .InstallState files are still in the folder, you can try reinstalling the executable to replace the files, then use InstallUtil /u, then uninstall the program.  It's a bit convoluted, but worked in a particular instance for me.

Answer (score 4):

You can try running [Autoruns](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx), which would save you from having to edit the registry by hand. This is especially useful when you don't have the needed permissions.

Answer (score 2):

Lots of great answers and this really helped me, but there was one thing that was missing. There's a mention of finding the service through cmd with `sc query type= service` but the problem is that the service I was looking for wasn't running and this command only shows running services (which may be a new feature that didn't exist at the time of the OP answer).

You have to pass the state of the service to the command like this `sc query state= all` or `sc query state= inactive` *There's no need to pass the type= service because that is the default*.

And, as stated above, push it to a text file so it's easier to search `sc query state= inactive > C:\servicesStopped.txt`

Source: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/sc-query

Answer (score 0):

You can uninstall your windows service by command prompt also just write this piece of command

```
cd\                                                                   

cd C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319(or version in which you developed your service)                                           

installutil c:\\xxx.exe(physical path of your service) -d
```

Answer (score 0):

1st Step : Move to the Directory where your service is present

Command : cd c:\xxx\yyy\service

2nd Step : Enter the below command

Command : C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\InstallUtil.exe service.exe \u

Here service.exe is your service exe and \u will uninstall the service. 
you'll see "The uninstall has completed" message.

If you wanna install a service, Remove \u in the above command which will install your service

Comment: The OP clearly said that the original files have been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

We discovered that even if you run `sc_delete`, there can be an entry remaining in the registry for your service, so that reinstalling the service results in a corrupted set of registry entries (they don't match). What we did was to `regedit` and remove this leftover entry by hand.

[image]
Note: ShipmunkService is still showing up after sc_delete!

Then you can reinstall, and your service will run correctly. Best of luck to you all, and may the force be with you.

Answer (score 0):

`-Windows+r` open cmd.

`-sc YourSeviceName` this code remove your service.

`-Uninstal "YourService Path"` this code uninstall your service.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way is to use [Sys Internals Autoruns](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/autoruns)

[image]

Start it in admin mode and then you can remove obsolete services by delete key