# Delete a Windows Service without the EXE

Tags: windows-services, windows-server-2008

I have a windows service running on a server (that I would rather not reboot if I can).

The EXE for this service is gone (beyond recovery) and I don't have a copy (it was a debugging version that has since been updated).

Is there anyway to remove this service from the services list without the exe that ran it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I uninstall a Windows service if the files does not exist anymore?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197876/how-do-i-uninstall-a-windows-service-if-the-files-does-not-exist-anymore)

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Have you tried `sc <server> delete [service name]` from the command line?

A more comprehensive answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197876/how-do-i-uninstall-a-windows-service-if-the-files-does-not-exist-anymore/197941#197941).

Answer (score 16):

Try:

```
sc delete servicename
```

Answer (score 14):

Note that sc delete servicename works, but the servicename is the 'KeyName'.

E.g. For Confluence, you will see "Atlassian Confluence" in the list of services.  This is the 'Descriptive' name.  To remove it type:

```
sc GetKeyName "Atlassian Confluence"
```

In my case this returned Confluence150114140910.  So I then typed:

```
sc delete Confluence150114140910
```

Answer (score 3):

Use [autoruns tool](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) (formerly by sysinternals, now on Microsoft site), it lets you manage services and drivers (their records in registry).

Answer (score 2):

You can also use the register

1. Start > Run > regedit
2. Goto HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Services
3. Delete the folder of your service.
4. Restart your system.

Answer (score 0):

this works great (need admin cmd )

```
C:\Windows\system32>sc GetKeyName "SERVER"
[SC] GetServiceKeyName Êxito
Nome = SERVER

C:\Windows\system32>sc delete "SERVER"
[SC] DeleteService Êxito

C:\Windows\system32>sc delete "SERVER 2"
[SC] DeleteService Êxito
```