# Re-install Windows Service - Fail

Tags: windows-services

I developed a Windows Service project, then I installed.

Then I made some changes in the project, and tried to re-build, but it didn't apply the changes. So, I tried to uninstall and install again, but appears an error: "The service already exists". I try to delete, reboot, but I'm still unable to re-install the service (The same error is showed).

Does anybody know how to fix it?

And when I make changes in the project, I need only stop the service and build the project, that the changes are applied?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If the Windows service is merely installed, you should be able to rebuild it without issue.  Running it after a re-build will then pick up any changes you've made.  However, if the service is running when you attempt to rebuild, you'll run into build issues because the assemblies are in use and cannot be changed.  Thus, you have to stop the service first, rebuild, and then re-run the service.

As far as dealing with the install/uninstall issue, you should find everything you need to address the issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/197876/how-do-i-uninstall-a-windows-service-if-the-files-does-not-exist-anymore/197941#197941).