# How to check and delete a windows service if it exists, using Batch command?

Tags: batch-file, window

Hi I need to check a windows services exist or not using batch command. if it exists need to delete it.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/76074/how-can-i-delete-a-service-in-windows

Comment: @ SomethingDark hi how to check the service exists or not before deleting it?

Comment: As it says **in the answer I linked**, use `SC QUERY`.

Comment: @ SomethingDark thanks, yes it return some string value. How can i handle it with if check?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this with Admin rights:

```
@echo off
sc query Name_of_the_service >nul && sc stop Name_of_the_service
```